# How to prioritize the events in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, uitextview

I have a two delegate events i.e. `navigateOut`(when the user navigates out of the app) and also `textViewDidEndEditing` (when user ends editing in the TextView).

The problem is the when I navigate out from one module first the `navigateOut` delegate function is getting called and then `textViewDidEndEditing` event is firing at last. 
Is there any way that I can control these ? I want to do some computation first in `textViewDidEndEditing` and then after that  in `navigateOut` function.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: what should exactly you want? can you explain in details?

Comment: I want to control the events i.e. I want to make textViewDidEndEditing as the first responder when I navigate out from the module and not the navigateOut delegate function

Comment: if navigateOut is your viewController delegate then call the delegate method in textViewdidEndEditing method. or can u show some of ur code if i am going wrong?

Comment: If I call navigateOut directly it will call every time when there is textViewDidEndEditing event. I don't want this to happen because even if the user edits something in the TextView and moves into the other tab without clicking the navigate out button then unnecessarily the navigateOut event is called. I am unable to post the code because of corporate policy. I am extremely sorry for this.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you can't change the order of when delegate methods are triggered. If you don't want to call navigateOut every time textViewDidEndEditing is called just set a flag if it is still progressing and reset it if done.

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (!isNavigatingOut) {
        [self navigateOut];
    }
}

- (void)navigateOut
{
    isNavigatingOut = YES;
    //do your stuff here
    //if finished set
    isNavigatingOut = NO;
}
```